# EF 6.1 Updating record - can't update relational properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a method that aims to update a Monitor Profile's Nodes and Attributes:

All of the primitive type of the entity (ProfileName, DisplayName) get updated fine.  However, on save changes, the Attributes and Nodes do not get modified.

Here is the entity itself:

```
public class NWatchMonProfile
{

    public NWatchMonProfile()
    {
        this.CasAttributes = new HashSet<NWatchAttribute>();
    }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string CreatedUser { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndedDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string EndedUser { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NWatchAttribute> CasAttributes { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NWatchNode> Nodes { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the MVC controller code that is being used to attempt to Update the record.

```
var monProfile = new NWatchMonProfile
                {
                    Id = profileId,
                    ProfileName = profileName,
                    DisplayName = profileName,
                    CasAttributes = attributes,
                    Nodes = nodes
                };

                monProfile.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                monProfile.DisplayName = profileName;
                monProfile.ProfileName = profileName;
                if (nodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    monProfile.Nodes = nodes;
                }

                monProfile.CasAttributes = attributes;

                var entry = dbContext.Entry(monProfile);
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Note:
I have verified that the "attributes" array contains a list of NWatchAttributes.
STE is no longer recommended by Microsoft.

Comment: `entry.State = EntityState.Modified` only affects the `entry` itself, not its navigation properties.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework not saving modified children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054798/entity-framework-not-saving-modified-children)

Comment: I read the related post and it mentioned self tracking entities.  Further research said that Microsoft no longer recommends this.  So, the question is, what is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: You could look into GraphDiff https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff

Comment: Have you tried setting `entry.State = EntityState.Modified` before setting the collection properties (e.g. `monProfile.Nodes = nodes`)? That way, EF could handle tracking your later changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dbContext.Entry(monProfile.Nodes).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.Entry(monProfile.CasAttributes).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.Entry(monProfile).State = EntityState.Modified;

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```